# deployment error in jboss fuse

Tags: xml, apache-camel, jbossfuse

for testing purpose i have a blueprint.xml like ,this. this blueprint contains a route that just handles an exception that is thrown in the same route, i declared a bean damn as an exception bean which throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:cxf-core="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="              http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" trace="false">


     <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:myService.properties"/>

    <!-- setup endpoint -->
    <!-- <endpoint id="dead" uri="mock:dead"/> -->
       <endpoint id="dead" uri="mock:dead"></endpoint>

    <!-- setup a common redelivery policy, using property placeholders -->
    <redeliveryPolicyProfile id="myRedelivery" redeliveryDelay="{{delay}}" maximumRedeliveries="{{max}}"/>


      <bean id="damn" class="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="Damn"/>
    </bean>


    <route id="exceptionroute">
       <from uri="direct-vm:csl-mpgs-payment-1.0-fromamq1"/> 
       <onException redeliveryPolicyRef="myRedelivery">
            <!-- refer to common redelivery policy -->
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <!-- but we can override the profile and log retry attempts at WARN level -->
            <redeliveryPolicy logRetryAttempted="true" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
            <to ref="dead"/>
        </onException>
         <throwException ref="damn"/> 
         <to uri="direct-vm:csl-mpgs-payment-1.0-fromam"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

when iam deploying to a fuse container i am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":redeliveryPolicyProfile, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":onException, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":onCompletion, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":intercept, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":interceptFrom, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":interceptSendToEndpoint, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":restConfiguration, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":rest, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":route}' is expected.
  at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.beginNode(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)[:]
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)[:]
  at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.parser.Parser.validate(Parser.java:314)
```

how to solve this???

Answer (score 2):

The `<bean>` should be outside `<camelContext>` as its a OSGi Blueprint bean definition, eg move it before `<camelContext>`